# How can I parse multiple time durations in python?

Tags: python

I´m working on a discord bot that has a feature to provide time durations like `1m`, `2d` for tempban/mutes and stuff.
Currently I try to figure out how I could use more than one of these durations like `1d12h`.

```
def convert(time):
    pos = ["s" ,"m", "h", "d","y"]
    time_dict = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 3600 * 24, "y": 86400 * 365}

    unit = time[-1]

    if unit not in pos:
        return -1
    try:
        val = int(time[:-1])
    except:
        return -2

    return val * time_dict[unit]
```

This function I currently use to convert single durations into seconds to work with that duration.
But I have no plan how I can use this for multiple time durations.

I tried parse_time() of the [humanfriendly](https://pypi.org/project/humanfriendly/) module but the function only allows a string input of one duration.
Is this even possible what I plan to do? Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the format of these multiple time durations? Some string with a delimeter, a list, ...?

Comment: Is the code above correct or is it just an example? Giving `convert("1d12h")` as input returns `-2`

Comment: The code above is an example how it works with a sigle duration like just "1m" or "1d" etc.

Comment: Ah now i get your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 100 ways to do this, but without spacing I'd do this (probably not the most efficient)

```py
def convert(timeString):
   out = 0
   current = ""
   timeDict = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 3600 * 24, "y": 86400 * 365}
   for char in timeString:
      if char.isdigit(): # For numbers, we will not support decimals here
         current += char # Add the number to the multiplication string
      elif char in timeDict: # Check if it's a valid key
         out += int(current) * timeDict[char] # Add the time
         current = "" # Reset the multiplication
   return out
```

I wrote this on my phone, pls lemme know if theres a syntax error

Comment: It is actually a TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable ;)  `timeDict[char]`

Comment: Thank you very much I thought of a for each but I didn´t came to a solution like you. Its working nicely. Thanks again.